# What is the best way to typeset an algorithm with several procedures?

Tags: algorithms

The title question sums it all.

Comment: I guess it would help a lot if you expand a bit in your question what you're aiming at.

Comment: It is just as simple as in the title. I have to typeset  algorithms with several procedures/functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use algorithmicx package, it allows function typesetting.